# SQL: Getting All fields That Have a Corresponding Matching Field

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get an answer that combines fields in 4 tables to show which fields have a specific relationship.

Here are the relevant tables & fields:

```
lowproducts
|productid|

highproducts
|productid|

orders
|productid|customerid|

inner join on productid
```

orders has many duplicates for both customerid and productid fields; lowproducts and highproducts only have distinct productid fields.

What I need is code that does this:

For all orders.customerid:
Select only fields where all rows for a customerid have a productid in either highproducts or lowproducts

Sample table data

```
lowproducts
|productid|volume|price|
|1111|8|2.95
|2222|7|1.37



highproducts
|productid|weight|price|
|3333|25|9.99
|4444|22|8

orders
|productid|customerid|
|1111|abcd
|2222|abcd
|1111|efgh
|2222|efgh
|3333|efgh
|4444|efgh

inner join on productid

select customerid, productid
where (orders.productid = highproducts.productid) or (orders.productid = lowproducts.productid)
```

That gets me all the matches. That's not hard for me. But how do I now refine it so that I only return the matches that represent all orders for a given customerid (which is to say, none of the orders for a customerid have productid that isn't in one of those two tables)?

The result I want would be efgh, and not abcd. I know how to get both abcd and efgh in a query, but not just efgh.

Comment: Join, Group by.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: What's the difference between lowproducts and highproducts? Can't you have just one table, products?

Comment: Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that you can ask a better question and we can help.

Comment: The problem is, I really don't know where to start, @jarlh .

Producing a list of rows from orders that have productids in either of lowproducts and highproducts isn't hard.

But then telling it to only return results where a given customerid has no non-matches is something I don't have any idea how to solve in SQL. In another language, I'd probably build an array and then query the array.

Comment: Start with sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: I've added sample data and expected result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

You want to exclude records where orders in the other products table exist, so you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. For example to get orders where the customer didn't order highproducts, exclude records where orders exist **for that customer** with products in the highproducts table Then do the same thing for lowproducts and Union them together:

```
SELECT *, 'only low' as type FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM orders p
JOIN highproducts on p.productid=highproducts.productid
WHERE o.customerid = p.customerid)
UNION
SELECT *, 'only high' FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM orders p
JOIN lowproducts on p.productid=lowproducts.productid
WHERE o.customerid = p.customerid)
```